# webworker message passing is not working

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, web-worker

The following are the codes of the main js and the worker js files:

```
main.js
function main(){
        var loadShWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
        var loadShWorkerMsgEvntListnr = function(e) {
            console.log("reached main");
          console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
        }
        // loadShWorker.port.start();
        loadShWorker.removeEventListener('onmessage',loadShWorkerMsgEvntListnr);
        loadShWorker.addEventListener('onmessage', loadShWorkerMsgEvntListnr, false);
        // loadShWorker.port.start();
      // loadShWorker.port.postMessage('Hello World');
        loadShWorker.postMessage('Hello World');
    }


worker.js
console.log("reached worker top");
self.addEventListener('onmessage', function(e) {
  console.log("reached worker");
  self.postMessage(e.data);
  console.log("posted msg from worker");
}, false);
```

Here the control is not reaching the main js file. Am I doing anything different

Comment: `loadShWorker.onmessage = loadShWorkerMsgEvntListnr;` instead of listener. and where you are call `main()`?

Comment: Main is called and initiated properly